# kendo ui grid within a window - window becomes invisible

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo UI 2013.1 and I have a grid within a window.  The window's visibility is set to false on the page load, but when a link is clicked, I make it visible.

The problem is that whenever you try to do anything with the grid, like use the filter, or use a paging button, the window becomes invisible.  When you click the link again, the window is visible again and reflects whatever the last action was - filtered results or on the next page.

I've tried several approaches that look similar to:

```
$("#outageWindow").kendoWindow({ visible: true });
```

But no luck.  Here is the full code without any of my resolution attempts:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("viewListWindow")
    .Title("Complete CI List")
    .Width(650)
    .Actions(actions => actions.Close())
    .Content(@<text>
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid(chg.CIsModifiedByChange.CIsModifiedByChange) //Bind the grid to ViewBag.Products
            .Name("grid")
            .RowAction(row =>        
            {          
                if (row.IsAlternate)            
                {                
                    //Set the background of the entire row                
                    //row.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "background:#e0f7ff;";   this is a lighter blue
                    row.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "background:#dde1ff;";                    
                }        
            })
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(ci => ci.Value).Title("CI Name");
            })
            .Pageable() // Enable paging
            .Sortable() // Enable sorting
            .Filterable() // Enable filtering
         )
    </text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Visible(false)
)

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#viewCI").bind("click", function () {
        $("#viewListWindow").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
    })
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution is work fine for me,

try this

```
function load_grid() {
/* your grid properties here */
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#viewCI").bind("click", function () {

      /* load window */
      $("#viewListWindow").data("kendoWindow").center().open();

      /* load grid into element inside window after window opened */
      load_grid();

   })
});
```